# How to wrap report for Word output in JasperReport?

Tags: ms-word, jasper-reports, export

I have report where report width is more than 2000px; it is working fine with pdf and excel output but when we export for word it is showing 550px; report only other part we are not able to see.

We have one report which contains ...

`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz`

when we export for excel or pdf it's working fine but when we export for word it's coming like

`abcdefg`

other parts are not visible.

I am exporting word report with JRRtfExporter object. is there any property i have to set to see full report or any suggestions ?

we are using `JasperReports` 1.2.0

Any Help Appreciated ...

Answer (score 0):

```
JasperPrint jasperPrint = null;

jasperPrint.setPageWidth(1500);
```

This is working fine but if some one has better solution please provide it...